# I need vertical text animation

Tags: animation, text, scroll

I need text scrolling animation like http://www.feedmusic.com/. How I can achieve this? Is there any ready made plugin which I can use?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need scroll event tracking.

This can be achieve with:

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(e) {
  //do stuff...
});
```

or with third party scripts like.

http://scrollmagic.io/

or with event libraries like:

https://hammerjs.github.io/